# Checking equality in SQL datetime conversions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hi I'm getting a strange problem while converting datetime in sql query

```
select * from employee where (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), doj , 110) 
>= '01/01/2008')
```

I'm getting results, but for the similar query:

```
select * from employee where (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), doj , 110) 
<= '01/01/2010')
```

I'm no getting results

Any specific reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert your string to datetime rather than converting datetime into string will resolve your issue

```
select * from employee where  doj  
<=  convert(dateteime,'01/01/2010',110)
```

Answer (score 3):

Comparing the values of a datetime column in a select statement would be a little tricky. Check on the result and you will notice that the datetime value includes the time "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss" and you are comparing your query to this "mm/dd/yyyy" which is mostly the reason why when most of the queries that have the same date does not return as the way you expected to.

So if you have this

```
column1  |  dateTimeColumn2
abc      |  01/24/2011 04:05:00
```

and your query is this

```
declare @param as datetime
set @param = '01/24/2011'

select * from table where dateTimeColumn = '01/24/2011'  
-- This would not return any because '01/24/2011' is written as '01/24/2011 00:00:00'
```

In your code, the best thing to do is

```
Select * 
from employee 
where Cast(Convert(varchar(25),doj,101) as Datetime) = Cast(Covert(varchar(25),parameter1,101) as datetime) 
--this will return a result
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're doing in the query is string comparison rather than date comparison.

Suppose `doj` is a datetime and its value is 01/02/2008.

In your query, the condition check will be 

`where ('01/02/2008' <= '01/01/2010')`

Because it's a string comparison, it will give a false. And the record won't be in the result.

In fact you can do this in mssql:

`select * from employee where doj>='01/01/2008'


select * from employee where doj<='01/01/2010'`

Answer (score 2):

If you need to have dates in string representation, I would recommend to **always** use the [ISO-8601 format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190977%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) (`YYYYMMDD`) since that works on all systems, regardless of locale/language/regional/dateformat settings.

Also, if your column `doj` is a `DATETIME` - why even convert it for comparison??

Why not use

```
WHERE doj >= '20080101' 
WHERE doj <= '20100101'
```

no conversion, no mess.....